# automatically download csv files from a website via query requests with for loop and delay

Tags: python, for-loop, download, request

I am trying to download a large amount of data (csv files)from a website with login (free), where each download requires a list of inputs from the user into their website before a single file can be downloaded. Luckily only 1 input needs to be changed per requests and the other inputs can be left alone. Also, this needs to be done between intervals using a for loop delay or other functions? (and cannot be done at once since their servers will crash otherwise). From the looks of it, there is a lot of ways to download files but I am fairly new to this and cannot find similar examples. The website is https://cliflo.niwa.co.nz/ and the input that needs to be changed between intervals is a list of numbers categorized as station agent numbers, looks like:[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

You will need selenium for this task.